# .htaccess RedirectMatch 301 pattern

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have three patterns that I want to redirect in .htaccess.

1. https://example.com/questions/name-of-question
2. https://example.com/category/name-of-category
3. https://example.com/a-4-digit-number/name-of-post

(The No. 3 like: https://example.com/5485/name-of-post)

all of them need a /blog/ after the domain:

1. https://example.com/blog/questions/name-of-question
2. https://example.com/blog/category/name-of-category
3. https://example.com/blog/a-4-digit-number/name-of-post

I used the code below for the first one, once it worked and then something happened and the htaccess got deleted. Now that I use it againg it does not redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RedirectMatch 301 https://example.com/questions/(.*) https://example.com/blog/questions/$1
```

Can anyone help me with these redirects? Specially the no. 3 with the 4-digit pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RewriteRule` directive like this to **target all the 3 rules into one pattern**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRUle ^/?(questions|category|\d{4})/.+$ /blog/$0 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: You are a saviour. Thank you so much.